# How to navigate to React screen from native android activity

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-community

I have 2 React native screen (MainScreen,Detail Screen) and 1 native android Activity(HomeActivity). Initially when app starts MainScreen loads then i am navigating to HomeActivity(Android activity). but from native i want to navigate to DetailScreen(React native) is this possible.

what i have done in Android activity i am emitting event to react native. but not able to listen this event in react native.

1. Navigate to Native screen called HomeActivity from React native
2. Native Activity to React native screen called Detail Screen

Comment: Specify your question. Give a an code sample.

Comment: How did you start the native activity from the react native?